# Java Mission Control (JMC) unable to change MBean attribute

Tags: java, jmx, mbeans, jmc

I am unable to change attribute of the registered MBean in JMC (v 7.1), jdk1.8.0_172

[image]

However, I am able to change it in **jconsole**

[image]

MBean definitions and registration:

```
public class ProfilingController implements ProfilingControllerMBean {
    private boolean enabled = false;

    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return enabled;
    }

    public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }
}

public interface ProfilingControllerMBean {
    void setEnabled(boolean enabled);
}


ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer().registerMBean(controller, new ObjectName("AppProfiling", "name", "ProfilingController"));
```

Comment: I opened https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JMC-6903.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem. I use java 21, JDK Mission Control 8.3.1+b05
[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YeUnq.png)

I noticed the error message "Could not find attribute Enabled"  and decided to add a get method to the interface and everything worked.

```
public interface ProfilingControllerMBean {
    void setEnabled(boolean enabled);

    boolean isEnabled();
}
```

```
public class ProfilingController implements ProfilingControllerMBean {
    private boolean enabled = true;

    @Override
    public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return enabled;
    }
}
```

Perhaps somewhere there is a description of the MBean convention and everything is described there.

[decided](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWWFi.png)
I hope it will be useful to someone.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)